# Requested url was not found on this server while accessing the directory using domain name

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a web application hosted on AWS on Ubuntu server. I have Apache and mysql running on it. It was working perfectly fine till yesterday, All of sudden when I try to access phpmyadmin using my domain name (like http://example.com/phpmyadmin) it gives 404 error.

If I simply type http://example.com on the browser it opens the home page, but if I click on any of the link of my site which refer to different directory, gives the same error.

I have checked the 000-default file under /etc/apache2/sites-enable. My Document Root is set perfectly fine, and directory has Override option to All.

Can any one have any idea then please help me.

Thanks

Comment: is there any htaccess?

Comment: Are you using an Elastic IP?